# Error:(2) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

I am using Android Studio with 
Compile sdk version:-API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
Build Tool Version:-23.0.2

and getting this error

Error:(2) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\AndroidSdk\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My Code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

< TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter your number to be doubled."/>
< EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>

        < Button
            android:id="@+id/doubleme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Double Me"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try removing the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any space between `<` character and the tag names, replce ur layout with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your number to be doubled."/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doubleme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Double Me"/>
</LinearLayout>
```